# Can you create a function that takes another function and a parameter and returns a lazy stream of nested function calls?

Tags: rust

In Clojure, I use a function called [`iterate`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate) that:

> Returns a lazy sequence of x, (f x), (f (f x)) etc. f must be free of side-effects

Is there something similar in Rust?

For example, I have this function that I'd like to pass to a function with a number and then iterate over a stream/range/vector until I find `Some(1)`:

```
fn coltz(n: u64) -> Option<u64> {
    match n % 2 {
        0 => Some(n / 2), 
        _ => Some(3 * n + 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can repeatedly call a closure using [`std::iter::repeat_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/fn.repeat_with.html):

```
repeat_with(move || {
    let result = x;
    x = f(x);
    result
})
```

The return value is an iterator over the successive return values of the closure.

We use `move` to move `x` into the closure, as the current state of our iteration.  Inside the closure we update `x` with `f(x)` and return the old value (so in the first iteration we return the original `x`).

Here is a complete working example:

```
use std::iter::repeat_with;

fn collatz(n: u64) -> u64 {
    match n % 2 {
        0 => n / 2,
        _ => 3 * n + 1,
    }
}

fn iterate<F, X>(f: F, mut x: X) -> impl Iterator<Item = X>
where
    F: Fn(X) -> X,
    X: Copy,
{
    repeat_with(move || {
        let result = x;
        x = f(x);
        result
    })
}

fn main() {
    for i in iterate(collatz, 12).take_while(|&x| x != 1) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3b9375df9984e45098f663c9af86cb66)

Answer (score 0):

As of Rust 1.34, you can use [`iter::successors`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.successors.html):

```
fn coltz(n: u64) -> Option<u64> {
    match n % 2 {
        0 => Some(n / 2),
        _ => Some(3 * n + 1),
    }
}

use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let sequence = iter::successors(Some(10), |&v| coltz(v)).take_while(|&v| v != 1);
    for v in sequence {
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}
```

```
12
6
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
```