# Why does my Hailstone Sequence function using recursion only output two values?

Tags: recursion, rust

I have the following code:

```
fn hailSeq(number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(number);
    if number == 1 {
        vec.push(1);
        return vec;
    }
    if number % 2 == 0 {
        let num = number / 2;
        vec.push(num);
        hailSeq(num);
    } else {
        let num = 3 * number + 1;
        vec.push(num);
        hailSeq(num);
    }
    return vec;
}
```

It calculates the [Hailstone sequence](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hailstone_sequence) and stops at 1. The output should look like this for `hailSeq(11)`:

```
[11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

However, my output looks like this:

```
[11, 34]
```

I am not really sure why this is occurring. Perhaps there is a limit on recursion in Rust that I don't know about, but I'm sure there's probably just an error in my code.

Comment: Please use `rustfmt` to format your code properly next time. Second, in rust we do not use camelCase, but snake_case, e.g. your function name should be hail_seq. Third, don't use an explicit `return` for the last statement, that is very unrusty. Just write `vec` (withouth return and `;`)

Comment: You may explain or link how to generate a hail sequence.

Comment: The more idiomatic in Rust is to [use an iterator](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=7ddbd3323cc319175982ef50bc2955c5).

Comment: The fun is there is an implementation for Rust on the link that I added https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hailstone_sequence#Rust ;)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905147/279627

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not Rust-specific, but a more general problem.

On every call of `hailSeq` you create a new `Vec` every time, so that only the first `vec` (from the first call) would be used and returned, hence the `[11, 34]` (`11` from the third line, `34` from the tenth line).

To fix this you have two options, I will provide one here.

The first one would be to extend the current `vec` with the returned `vec`, e.g. `myvec.extend_from_slice(&returned_vec)`.

The second solution involves creating a `vec` on startup and passing the same instance to every call of the function.

```
fn hail_seq(number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    fn inner(number: i32, vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
        vec.push(number);
        if number == 1 {
            return;
        }
        if number % 2 == 0 {
            let num = number / 2;
            inner(num, vec);
        } else {
            let num = 3 * number + 1;
            inner(num, vec);
        }   
    }
    let mut v = vec![];
    inner(number, &mut v);
    v
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", hail_seq(11));
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=9b9794d0379770c6676ad8933ef7fe62))

As a side-note: If you know that a number can't be negative, use a `u32` instead because you will find errors at compile time instead of runtime.