# Is there an equivalent to Haskell's iterate in Rust?

Tags: rust

Haskell's [`iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) function repeatedly applies a function to a value to generate a series of values. For example, applying (^2) to 2 generates 2, 2^2, 2^2^2, 2^2^2^2, ... (2, 4, 16, 256, ...)

Is there an equivalent in Rust?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you create a function that takes another function and a parameter and returns a lazy stream of nested function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902081/can-you-create-a-function-that-takes-another-function-and-a-parameter-and-return)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not exist in the standard library, however the [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate has [`iterate`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/fn.iterate.html)

> Creates a new iterator that infinitely applies function to value and yields results.

```
use itertools::iterate;

itertools::assert_equal(iterate(1, |&i| i * 3).take(5), vec![1, 3, 9, 27, 81]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As of [Rust 1.34](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/04/11/Rust-1.34.0.html#library-stabilizations), you can use `std::iter::successors`

So for this problem you would do something like this:

[playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00521a0725e2b176fd5407d7c3de8d4f)

```rust
use std::iter::successors;

fn main() {
    let v = successors(Some(2_u128), |n| n.checked_mul(*n)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    assert_eq!(v, vec![2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, 4294967296, 18446744073709551616]);

    for i in successors(Some(2_u128), |n| n.checked_mul(*n)) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Also look at [`std::iter::from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html), it can be quite a bit more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools::iterate`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/fn.iterate.html) seems to be what you want.