# How do I implement an `apply_n_times` function?

Tags: rust, closures

How do I implement an `apply_n_times` function which gets a function `f: T -> T` and a number `n` and the result will be a function which applies `f` `n`times?

E.g. `apply_n_times(f, 0)` equals `|x| x` and `apply_n_times(f, 3)` equals `|x| f(f(f(x)))`.

There is no deeper sense in this function, I just want to implement it for learning reasons.

My current code:

```rust
fn apply_n_times<T>(f: Fn(T) -> T, n: i32) -> dyn Fn(T) -> T {
    if n < 0 {
        panic!("Cannot apply less than 0 times!");
    }

    if n == 1 {
        |x: T| x
    } else {
        |x| f(apply_n_times(f, n - 1)(x))
    }
}

fn times_two(n: i32) -> i32 {
    return n * 2;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", apply_n_times(times_two, 0)(3));
    println!("{}", apply_n_times(times_two, 1)(3));
    println!("{}", apply_n_times(times_two, 3)(3));
}
```

I'm at chapter 13 of the Rust book, but I searched forward a bit. I probably have to return a `Box`, but I'm not really sure. I tried it and I failed.

I also wanted to change the signature to this, but this only results in problems:

```
fn apply_n_times<F, T>(f: F, n: i32) -> F
where
    F: Fn(T) -> T,
```

Unfortunately, the compiler errors do not help me; they say what's wrong at a low level, but I was running in a circle.

Comment: Some alternative ways of iterating a function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52902081

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fn apply_n_times<T>(f: impl Fn(T) -> T, n: usize) -> impl Fn(T) -> T {
    move |arg| (0..n).fold(arg, |a, _| f(a))
}
```

Using a `usize` avoids the need for the negative check. Consider using `FnMut` instead of `Fn` as it's more flexible for users of the function.

See also:

- [Can you create a function that takes another function and a parameter and returns a lazy stream of nested function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52902081/155423)
- [How to use the Fn traits (closures) in Rust function signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26577070/155423)
- [Returning a closure from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445761/155423)

Comment: Thanks, especially for the references :)!

Comment: I think using `u32` or `u64` makes more sense here, since the length isn't used as a pointer offset or something similar and its size doesn't need to be platform dependent.